# How to add a z-index to separate image from div border

Tags: html, css

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0qqnvrdg/

HTML:

```
<div class="loading"></div>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
  background: #0d8aa5;
}

.loading {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 25%;
  /*margin: -60px 0 0 -60px;*/
  background: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 10px solid #19bee1;
}
.loading:after {
  content: '';
  background: trasparent;
  width: 140%;
  height: 140%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: -20%;
  left: -20%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) -4px -5px 3px -3px;
  animation: rotate 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
.loading:before {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTnLP.png');
    background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    width: 85%; 
    height: 85%;
    content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 10%;
}
```

How can I modify the CSS to that the image is under the thin blue border while being on top of the white.

Is that possible?

Comment: Side note, you have a typo in `background: trasparent;`

Comment: @j08691 Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

added z-index: -1000; for under.

ps: nice effect for scrollbar )

```css
body {
  background: #0d8aa5;
}
.loading {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 25%;
  /*margin: -60px 0 0 -60px;*/
  background: transparent;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 10px solid #19bee1;
}
.loading:after {
  content: '';
  background: trasparent;
  width: 140%;
  height: 140%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: -20%;
  left: -20%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) -4px -5px 3px -3px;
  animation: rotate 2s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
.loading:before {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTnLP.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to achieve it but you beat me to it :)

Comment: Hmmmmmm... works with localhost but doesn't work through IIS. Could be the IE version on the server?

Comment: wa? ie is a client. in stackoverflow snippet over ie11.0.9600 is a working

Answer (score 2):

`.loading {overflow: hidden}` - just add this line

Answer (score 0):

It is Because You are adding Background image before div.loading that makes images as content.Instead add background image to div.